# University Level Statistics Probability Questions

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

> 1. A person shows you a bag that has one red ball. He then adds another ball, which has a 50/50 chance of being either red or green. He then randomly takes out a ball, and it turns out to be red. What is the probability that the other ball is red as well?
> 2. A hockey team has 10 games left in the season. The probability that they win each game is 0.4, and are independent of each other. A turnover is defined as occurring when the team goes from a win to a loss, or a loss to a win. What is the probability that the team ends up with one turnover in the last 10 games.

Comment: Do we know the color of the ball in the bag of part 1?

Comment: Oops, the first line should read:
"A person shows you a bag that has one red ball."

Comment: In 2. you want "exactly 1 turnover" or "at least 1 turnover"?

Comment: Exactly one turnover. As a bonus, can you find E(turnover)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**For 1.** Denote with $R_2$ the event that the added ball was red (then $R^c_2$ is the complementary event, that the second ball was green) and with $D$ the event that the ball you draw is red. Then we want to calculate $P(R_2 \mid D)$ We have by Bayes' rule that $$P(R_2 \mid D)=\frac{P(D\mid R_2)P(R_2)}{P(D)}=\frac{1\cdot \frac12}{P(D)}$$ Now, we can calculate $P(D)$ with the Law of total probability $$P(D)=P(D\mid R_2)P(R_2)+P(D\mid R_2^c)P(R_2^c)=1\cdot\frac12+\frac12\cdot\frac12=\frac34$$ Hence $P(R_2 \mid D)=\frac{\frac12}{\frac34}=\frac23$

---

**For 2.** We want exactly 1 turnover. Let's take first the case that the turnover occurs as WL (win then loss). This can happen in the following ways:

1. Matches $1$ and $2$ and then all loses. String: (WL)LLLLLLLL.
2. In the middle. It must be precented by a win and followed by a loss (otherwise more turnovers will occur). String: ...W(WL)L... This can occur in places $(2,3),(3,4),\ldots,(8,9)$, i.e. starting in matchday $2, 3, 4, \ldots, 8$. ($7$ possibilities).
3. Matches $9$ and $10$ and before all wins. String: WWWWWWWW(WL).

The first string has probability $0.4\cdot0.6^9$ the other $7$ strings different probabilities which are $0.4^k\cdot0.6^{10-k}$ for $k=2,3,\ldots 8$ and the last string $0.4^9\cdot0.6^1$. So, the total probability of this scenario is $$\sum_{k=1}^{9}0.4^k\cdot0.6^{10-k}=0.6^{10}\sum_{k=1}^{9}\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^k=0.6^{10}\cdot\left(\frac23\frac{1-(2/3)^{9}}{1-(2/3)}\right)=2\cdot0.6^{10}\left(1-(2/3)^9\right)$$ The summation was simplified by the formula of the geometric sum $$\sum_{k=1}^{n}p^k=p\frac{1-p^{n}}{1-p}$$ for $|p|\neq 1$. Here $p=2/3$.

Repeat for the case that the turnover occurs as LW, which due to symmetry gives the same probability. So, the result (the probability of exactly $1$ turnover) is given by $$2\sum_{k=1}^{9}0.4^k\cdot0.6^{10-k}=4\cdot0.6^{10}\left(1-(2/3)^9\right)\approx 0.02356$$

Comment: This is where I get confused. I understand the use of Baye's rule, but aren't the individual probabilities different depending on which ball (red or green) is added? 

Just to clarify as well, P(D) is the probability that the first ball drawn is red, and P(R2) is the probability that the second ball drawn is red.

Comment: We use conditional probabilities $P(A \mid B)$ and they take into account these differences. Now, $P(D)$ is the probability that the single ball that is drawn is red (there is no first and second drawn) and $P(R_2)$ is the probability that the added ball is red.

Comment: Ah I finally understand. Could we solve it another way that's a big easier by just listing the possible outcomes and then finding the ones that fit? Ex:

Original red ball drawn, other red ball remains
Added red ball drawn, original red ball remains
Original red ball drawn, added green ball remains

Therefore 2/3 of the events have 2 red balls drawn. Or is this just a coincidence

Comment: No, it is not a coincidence. You certainly can do it the way you propose. It works well because the "list" of possible outcomes is short. It would work anyway, but sometimes listing all possible outcomes is not so easy.

Comment: For question 2, how exactly did you simplify the summation? I got lost. Also, wouldnt the two probabilities be the same? Since WWWWWWWWWL is the same probability as LWWWWWWWWW but backwards in sequence. How would you find the expected value of E(T) without having to solve for all values of T?

Comment: Yes, you are right. I corrected my answer. I did not find E(T), just P(T=1). The summation is the geometric sum. I will edit my answer to add this.

Comment: @RichardYang Is it clear now?

Comment: Yes, that is great. Just a final question if you still have time, how would you easily find E(T) without finding P(T) for every value of T?

Comment: @RichardYang Hmmm. I do not know. The only way to avoid P(T) for every value, is to determine the distribution of T, and find that it is a well known distribution (say binomial). But I do not know what the distribution of T is.

Comment: Fair enough. That was the gist of the question anyways, I think going any further would be above my paygrade.

Comment: @RichardYang I will think over it, perhaps there is a simple way to determine E(T) that I am currently missing.

Comment: Sounds great. The method i've seen is just E(T) = 9*0.4*0.6

Comment: @RichardYang This looks indeed like the expectation of a binomial distribution with $n=9$ and $p=0.4$ but I cannot explain right know why this works. Perhaps: There are $n=9$ opportunities for a turnover and each one occurs with probability $p=0.4$, but I am not sure. Perhaps you can explain why this works?

Comment: Wouldn't p = 0.4*0.6, since both a loss and win are needed in succession for a "successful" turnover? I am not sure if this is the correct answer, just speculation.

Comment: @RichardYang I find it very confusing. For example 2 turnovers can occur either as $WLLLLLLLLW$ or as $LWLLLLLLLL$.

Answer (score 0):

For the second question, observe that once a turnover happens, the last outcome must be repeated until the last game (e.g. If a team won before the turnover, then the turnover is a loss, and the team loses each subsequent game, or else there would be another turnover). Also note that a turnover cannot happen on the first game.

Denote the sequence of outcomes by a string of W's and L's, representing wins and losses. The sequences we are looking for take the form WLLLLLLLLL (1W, 9L), WWLLLLLLLL (2W, 8L), ..., WWWWWWWWWL (9W, 1L), and LWWWWWWWWW (1L, 9W), LLWWWWWWWW (2L, 8W), ..., LLLLLLLLLW (9L, 1W).

The probability of a given sequence is $P(W)^{\text{Number of wins}}*P(L)^{\text{Number of losses}}$. So the probability that any of these sequences occurs is $\sum_{k=1}^9 2(0.4)^k(0.6)^{10-k}$.